# High Availability deployments to a Static Website hosted in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting

At AWS, in the classical architecture of Route53 (domain management) -> CloudFront (HTTPS management) -> S3 (storing website).

I wonder how to do High Availability deployments. I.e., when deploying a new version of your website, some files can have dangling references for a tiny bit of time.

Is it possible to cache the previous site in CloudFront and then evict the caches? Is there any other solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could have it set to trigger a Lambda function once you've deployed that would purge the cache on CloudFront. Depending on how you deploy to S3 this could be automated by that process at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of invalidating entire cache, the CloudFront [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) recommends two alternative ways:

> **Invalidate the file** from edge caches. The next time a viewer requests the file, CloudFront returns to the origin to fetch the latest version of the file

Using this way you invalidate the individual files with those dangling references.

> Use **file versioning** to serve a different version of the file that has a different name. For more information, see Updating Existing Files Using Versioned File Names.

Here your website would refer to old or new version of those sites with dangling references. W

Comment: Note: invalidating each individual files can cost more than invalidating /*.